# Safari 5: How to create bookmarks via AppleScript in special folder/ for >1 Tabs?

Tags: safari, applescript, bookmarks

How can I create a bookmark for

a) the current tab
b) all tabs in the current safari window
  in an already existing bookmarks folder via Apple Script?

(Why? I want to define keyboard shortcuts for 3 or 4 different folders 
to quickly sort my bookmarks already when saving them.) 
After launching the script, i'd like to also get a text input box to 
define

- for (a) the name of the bookmark (default value like when hitting cmd- 
  D)
- and for (b) the name of the bookmarks folder to create with all the 
  tab's bookmarks. 
  Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this script from OSXHints.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060227192533174

Comment: thanks, that looks interesting. At a first attempt I could not make it work, as it did something but I cannot find the created bookmarks folder afterwards. I'll have to try it out if I have more time.